# React: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why do I get the error `Unterminated JSX contents` for the closing `div`-element? What am I doing wrong?

```
export default class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ui icon input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <i class="circular search link icon"></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue is, you forgot to close your `input` element, in `JSX` you have to close all the opened `tags` properly like in `XML`.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/):

> JSX is a XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript without any defined
>   semantics. It's intended to be used by various preprocessors
>   (transpilers) to transform these tokens into standard ECMAScript.

One more thing, `class` is a reserved keyword, to apply any `css` class instead of using the `class` keyword, use `className`.

Try this:

```
export default class Search extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="ui icon input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
            <i className="circular search link icon"></i>
         </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` JSX element is not terminated, it is missing a closing tag.

And `class` is a reserved name in Javascript. You need to use the `className` prop instead.

```
<div className="ui icon input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
    <i className="circular search link icon"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return  (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <button>Increment</button>
            </div>
        );        
    }
}

export default Counter;
```